# How to use NTLM authentication on flutter webview?

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying to make a request manually with using NTLM authentication and then loading the response data using loadHTMLString. But response body html text not has all css and js codes inside it. How can we use flutter webview package with NTLM authentication to load all html,css,js codes on webview ?